# JDK 1.8 to JDK 1.5 - Web App Deployement Potential Problems

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, tomcat

I am about to develop a simple web application which has only one registration page. I am planning to develop it with `JSP, Servlet & Hibernate`.

I am about to develop this application in `JDK 1.8` & `Tomcat 6` as Application Server. But problem is deployment server has `IBM WebSphere & JDK 1.5` installed.

I will create `.WAR` file and extract it on `IBM WebSphere`.

**I want to know what are potential that will come in each step from development to deployment process.**

Comment: That your code is not deployable. Also tomcat is not an application server

Comment: If your code uses any class or feature that is not common to JDK 5 and JDK 8 it'll fail.  You have my sympathies being stuck with WebSphere.  JDK 5 is terribly out of date.  Your bigger concern should be upgrading WebSphere.  No one should be running a JDK that isn't version 8, especially in production.  All earlier JDKs have passed the end of their support life.

Comment: @duffymo Good to know. I expect no update in environment at deployment server, because other application are running on same server. As you can consider, Registration application will not have any critical code.

Comment: You and your employer are foolish to not update your production server.   JDK 6 went live in Dec 2006.  You've missed a decade of bugs fixes and  security updates.  You should tell your clients so they can do business elsewhere.  You should find another job with an employer that isn't so irresponsible.  If you can run locally on Tomcat you can run in PROD on Tomcat.  Ditch WebSphere and run on Tomcat.

Comment: Tomcat 6 is out of support.

Comment: Java versions are backward compatible, which means that code written for an older version will almost always run on a newer version without modification. But the other way around does not work. If upgrading the server is no option, then the safest option is to use JDK 5 to develop your application. You can still get JDK 5 from the [Java Archive](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/archive-139210.html), but you do need to create an account on Oracle's website to download it.